# cakephp - passing url params to the homepage

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to build a link to my homepage which includes a param in the url

the way I'm trying is

```
echo '<a href="'.$this->webroot.'cat:garden'">Garden</a>';
```

But if I do that I get an error "You don't have permission to access the requested object."

I know I can do

```
echo '<a href="'.$this->webroot.'pages/home/cat:garden'">Garden</a>';
```

with the 'pages/home' included but it doesn't look as nice when you hover over the link or visit the page. It would be nicer if it was just www.whatever.com/cat:garden

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: That is not how it should ever be done. Use the Html->link() method - see the docs for that.

Comment: even if I do echo $this->Html->link($value, array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home', $value)); it still gives me the ugly long url includeing the pages/home bit.

Comment: still, is better to fix a `$this->Html->link` with ugly long url than a static url reference. And for the nicer url "www.whatever.com/cat:garden", please edit the question adding your routes.php

Answer (score 0):

Do thin in CakePHP way-

### In your view:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Garden', array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'home',
    $value)
);
```

this will generate `www.example.com/pages/home/garden`

**Now do the magic By *Router***

### In your routes.php:

Add this lines in the middle of routes.php file-

```
Router::connect('/pages/home/*', array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'home')
);
```

after adding new route, refresh your page. Now your $this->Html->link will generate `www.example.com/garden`